# Run executable with args inside container based on windows server 1709

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile, windows-server-2016

I have created image for container based on Windows Server 1709.
During image build i run powershell script (in dockerfile)

```
RUN powershell -NoProfile "& ""C:\...\Install.ps1"""
```

Inside this script i try to run executable with arguments

```
& "$PSScriptRoot\example.exe" /install /q
```

The problem is in arguments are not being applied to executable.
But if i run this command manually in powershell inside container then it works perfectly.
So i have tried to do this by different ways

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$PSScriptRoot\example.exe" -ArgumentList @("/install", "/q")


cmd /c "C:\...\example.exe" /install /q


cmd.exe /c "$PSScriptRoot\example.bat"
```

Everything works during manual execution via powershell and no one during script execution. There were a lot of different variations that not included in this list.

Note! The process inside container is being run always, but it's not configured by arguments when we do that via script execution.

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.16299.431
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.16299.431
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Do you have your `ExecutionPolicy` for PowerShell configured?

Comment: So `example.exe` runs, but no arguments are passed to it? And if you invoke the _script_ manually (not the command from inside the script) you see the same thing?

Comment: When i invoke script manually then it works perfectly. I simply connect to container and type this command in his powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$PSScriptRoot\example.exe" -ArgumentList "/install","/q"
```

'Example 7' at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1